# what the solution of this error ( Target SDK version 30 requires a minimum of signature scheme v2 )

Tags: android, sdk, apk, android-keystore, target-sdk

what the solution of this error ( Target SDK version 30 requires a minimum of signature scheme v2 )

Error de apksigner: ERROR: MIN_SIG_SCHEME_FOR_TARGET_SDK_NOT_MET: Target SDK version 30 requires a minimum of signature scheme v2; the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3rKS.jpg)APK is not signed with this or a later signature scheme

Comment: Please edit your question to include any pertinent detail. This is not an answer, please include the detail in your QUESTION and delete this 'answer' .

Answer (score 1):

This simple solution worked for me: after you run your `.\zipalign` run this command:

```
apksigner sign --ks yourkeystore.keystore yourapk.apk
```

To verify the signing:

```
apksigner verify -v yourapk.apk
```

This allowed me to sign with v3 and now I can upload to store no problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a release app it gives you options to sign , just check the V2 signature box and proceed everything should be fine after that

Comment: Thanks Faisal , where is the V2 option, in APK Easy Tool?